# mapping objects inside another mapping react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects

i am trying to map an object that is inside another object and i have tried to use this code inside a scrollview:

```
{Object.entries(exceptions).map(([key, value]) => {
  Object.entries(value).map(([num, photo]) => {
    let Qnum = num;
    let qType = key;
    let image = photo;
    return (
      <CustomCard
        questionNumber={Qnum}
        questionType={qType}
        image={image}
        key={`${key}, ${value}, ${photo}`}
      />
    );
  });
})}
```

the object looks like this:

`{"Qtype":{"key":val},"another":{"key":val}}`

this doesn't return the card i want

Comment: The above code returns an array or array of arrays not component(s).

Comment: so, how to return components from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just mapping in the 2D array. Just add an return statement before second loop or else just remove your `{}` brackets

```
{Object.entries(exceptions).map(([key, value]) =>
    Object.entries(value).map(([num, photo]) => {
      let Qnum = num;
      let qType = key;
      let image = photo;
      return (
            <CustomCard
              questionNumber={Qnum}
              questionType={qType}
              image={image}
              key={`${key}, ${value}, ${photo}`}
            />
      );
    });
  })
```